# jquery datepicker calendar position is showing off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using datepicker as below. I have noticed that calendar is opened off screen. when I unzoom the page, I can see it's open at very very bottom of the screen. I have tried z-index but it's not working.

Please advise and thanks in advance.

```
//css
datepicker_carry_forward_date{

      background-color: yellow;
      z-index: 999999;

}


//html
<input type = "text" id = "datepicker_carry_forward_date" autocomplete="off">


//js

$('#datepicker_carry_forward_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeYear: false,
            changeMonth: false,
            minDate: $scope.minimundate,
            maxDate: $scope.max_days,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    
                show = true;
              
              var holidays = ['06/16/2020','06/23/2020'];
    
                for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    
                    var holiday = new Date(holidays[i]);
                    holiday.setHours(00);
                    holiday.setMinutes(00);
                    holiday.setSeconds(00);
                    if (holiday.toString() == date.toString()) { show = false; break;}//No Holidays
                }
              
              if(date.getDay() == 0){ show = false; }
    
                var display = [show,'',(show)?'':'No Weekends or Holidays'];//With Fancy hover tooltip!
    
                return display;
    
            },
             onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                
                var date = $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
                console.log(date);
                
                
                
            }
    });
    [![when I unzoom screen I can see datepicker at bottom][1]][1]
```

Comment: Could be a conflict with some other css you are using. Create a runnable [mre] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax mistakes in html css and js... I tried to fix your code but I don't know what's in variable `$scope` but my variant is working.

```js
$('#datepicker_carry_forward_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  changeYear: false,
  changeMonth: false,
  minDate: 10, /// changed
  maxDate: 2, /// changed
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {

    show = true;

    var holidays = ['06/16/2020', '06/23/2020'];

    for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {

      var holiday = new Date(holidays[i]);
      holiday.setHours("00");
      holiday.setMinutes("00");
      holiday.setSeconds("00");
      if (holiday.toString() == date.toString()) {
        show = false;
        break;
      } //No Holidays
    }

    if (date.getDay() == 0) {
      show = false;
    }

    var display = [show, '', (show) ? '' : 'No Weekends or Holidays']; //With Fancy hover tooltip!

    return display;

  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

    var date = $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    }).val();
    console.log(date);



  }
});
```

```css
#datepicker_carry_forward_date {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker_carry_forward_date" autocomplete="off">
```